# Adding Possible Duplication Above Original Question

Tags: discussion, edits, duplicate-questions

After reading a question today I realized it was a possible duplicate of something I posted a few weeks back and earned bounty for. I decided to flag the question and add a link to my question on top

----------------------------
--
--
--    Possible Duplication Link
--
--
----------------------------

I figured if the post was closed then atleast people can see my previous post.

After an argument with @Erno (who disagreed with my action) he told me to post here.

I see this done all the time. What does everyone think?

#### EDIT

Sooooo I thought giving a downvote meant that its a BAD question. This isn't a BAD question. Its a valid question that people DO NOT know the answer to. Im only doing it because I followed others..but whatever.

Comment: For reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9195177/loading-image-from-isolated-storage-to-observable-collection-not-working

Comment: [This question in question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9195177/loading-image-from-isolated-storage-to-observable-collection-not-working); including your snarky comments =)

Comment: [Downvotes on Meta simply mean disagreement, not that the question is poorly formed](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences).

Comment: Ugh....I'm going to stick to programming.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The duplicate link is added automatically *if* enough people vote for the question to be closed as a duplicate (or a moderator does so).

You should *not* add those manually yourself.

You can:

- Leave a comment with the link, saying you think it's a duplicate. This won't do anything apart from alerting the people viewing the question.
- Use the "Flag" link, select the "It doesn't belong here" flag reason, then the "Exact duplicate" option. The flag will be visible to 10k users and moderators.
- Once you get 3k rep, cast a "close as duplicate" vote. (This adds a comment automatically.)

The first two options are not mutually exclusive, you can do both. None of the above options grant you the right to snarky comments.

Comment: Another option is to flag it as a duplicate (if you're under 3K).  That's what I do =)

Comment: I think that's what MyKuLLSKI did already. Can't remember if that adds the "possible duplicate" comment or not.

Comment: As there is no Duplicate option under flag, you can only flag it using the Other field so an automatic "possible duplicate" comment is hardly possible.

Comment: @Erno: no, you can flag as "it doesn't belong here", then "exact dup".

Comment: @Mat Correct!  Also, it does not add the "possible duplicate" comment automatically.

Comment: @Mat - I stand corrected. Apparently this didn't happen.

Comment: @Mat: no, what he did already was to edit the original question to add a very ugly duplicate message. The automatically added comment wouldn't have drawn any comment at all.

Comment: @Wooble: that's what I sort of figured out after having seen the link (and why I edited my answer). OP does say he/she "flagged" the post though.